# Laravel 4 unable to join on multiple conditions using ->on( ) more than once

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4, left-join

In a nutshell I am trying to do a join with more than one condition.  We are using legacy Laravel 4, and the actual class I've tracked it to is `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.  Here is what I am adding:

```
->leftJoin('node_fields AS visible_for_categories', function($join){
    $join->on('nv2.id',  '=', 'visible_for_categories.node_version_id');
    $join->on('visible_for_categories.name', '=', 'visible_for_categories');
})
```

It works fine with the first `$join->on( )` call, but the page fails if the second `on` is called.  why is this and what is the proper way to do this in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 1):

The way that worked for me on the above query is as follows:

```
->leftJoin('node_fields AS visible_for_categories', function($join){
    $join->on('nv2.id',  '=', 'visible_for_categories.node_version_id');
    $join->on('visible_for_categories.name', '=', DB::raw("'visible_for_categories'"));
})
```

The query builder will assume all three values in the `on()` function are fields, not strings, and will parse out the `.` period as well.

The general assumption is that JOINS will have the relational field joins to create structure, and the WHERE conditionals will provide the desired filter.  However anyone who's worked esp. with LEFT or RIGHT joins knows this is not always possible.

Be careful for SQL injection using `DB::raw` but in this case, an EAV table, we're dealing with a fixed string, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
->leftJoin('node_fields AS visible_for_categories', function($join){
    $join->on('nv2.id',  '=', 'visible_for_categories.node_version_id')
    ->on('visible_for_categories.name', '=', 'visible_for_categories');
})
```

Comment: no, this also causes it to fail (wind up with a bunch of redirects)

Comment: It can be the second join `'visible_for_categories.name', '=', 'visible_for_categories'`  is wrong ? Did you mean `'visible_for_categories.name', '=', 'nv2.name'`? or something like that?